# Implementing Merge Sort Generally in C

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to create a general merge sort implementation. I 99% sure the issue has to do with the fact that I'm using `memcpy` incorrectly.

Here's the code I have for merging 2 arrays:

```
static inline void * merge(void *left, void *right,
          size_t leftsz, size_t rightsz, size_t width, DArray_compare cmp)
{
  size_t i = 0, k = 0, j = 0;
  size_t sz = leftsz + rightsz;
  void *res = NULL;

  res = calloc(sz, width);
  check_mem(res);

  while (j < sz) {
    if (i == leftsz) {
      memcpy(res + j*width, right + k*width, width);
      ++i;
    } else if (k == rightsz) {
      memcpy(res + j*width, left + i*width, width);
      ++k;
    } else if (cmp(left + i*width, right + k*width) < 0) {
      debug("Here");
      memcpy(res + j*width, left + i*width, width);
      ++i;
    } else {
      memcpy(res + j*width, right + k*width, width);
      ++k;
    }

    debug("------PRINTING RES------\n");
    for (int t = 0; t < j; t++) {
      debug("%s\n", * (char **) res + t);
    }
    debug("----FINISHED PRINTING RES----\n");

    ++j;
  }

  return res;

error:
  return NULL;
}
```

where `sz` is the size of final merged array, `leftsz` is the size of the left half, and `rightsz` is the size of the right half. `width` refers to how large each element is.

Whenever I run this over the array `{ "asdfasfd", "werwar", "13234", "asdfasfd", "oioj" }`, it says that the array wasn't sorted correctly.

Here's the main merge sort code:

```
int merge_sort(void *arr, size_t size,
      size_t width, DArray_compare cmp)
{
  if (size <= 1)
    return 0;

  size_t lsize = size / 2, rsize = size - (size / 2);
  void *left = NULL, *right = NULL, *res = NULL;

  left = calloc(lsize, width);
  check_mem(left);

  right = calloc(rsize, width);
  check_mem(right);

  memcpy(left, arr, lsize*width);
  memcpy(right, arr + lsize*width, rsize*width);

  debug("Looping over right array.");
  for (int i = lsize; i < size; i++) {
    debug("%s", * ((char **) right + (i-lsize)));
  }

  merge_sort(left, lsize, width, cmp);
  merge_sort(right, rsize, width, cmp);


  res = merge(left, right, lsize, rsize, width, cmp);
  check_mem(res);

  free(left);
  free(right);

  memcpy(arr, res, size*width);
  free(res);

  return 0;

error:
  if (left) free(left);
  if (right) free(right);
  if (res) free(res);
  return -1;
}
```

Again, I'm sure that my implementation is screwing up because of `memcpy`. However, I'm not sure exactly how I'm using it wrong.

I ran the `merge_sort` function over the array `{ "asdfasfd", "werwar", "13234", "asdfasfd", "oioj" }` like so:

```
int rc = merge_sort(words->contents, words->end,
        sizeof(void *), (DArray_compare) testcmp);
...
```

`words->contents` is a `void **` array and `words->end` is the size of the array. `words` itself is a structure that represents a dynamic array. I know that the array was correctly built, so I don't think that's the root of the problem.

Feel free to ask me for more information if necessary.

Thanks.

Edit:

Here's an example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *words[] = { "asdfasfd",
      "werwar", "13234", "asdfasfd", "oioj"};
  merge_sort((void **)&words, 5,
        sizeof(void *), testcmp);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (strcmp(words[i], words[i+1]) > 0) {
          printf("NOT SORTED\n");
          return 1;
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's an infinite loop, you're never updating `j`.

Comment: Looks like that wasn't copy-pasted over. I'll fix that.

Comment: No, Don't fix it because then we don't know what else "wasn't copy-pasted". Instead, create a minimal example which you **tested** and post that. See [mcve].

Comment: what is the first code, a sub part of the definition of _merge_ ? why do you not give all the definition of _merge_ ? we cannot see how you initialize _j_ etc

Comment: I use cmp in `merge()` in `cmp(left + i*width, right + k*width)`

Comment: `if (i == leftsz)` should probably be `if (i >= leftsz)`, and similarly for `k` and `rightsz`. Also, arithmetic on `void *` is not standard C - it's a GNU extension.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi How would I assign `void *` to each other? As far as I know, this isn't really that safe to do in C, right?

Comment: Also, in the `if (i == leftsz)` part, you copy from position `k` of `right`, but increment `i`. Shouldn't it increment `k`? Similarly, shouldn't `if (k == rightsz)` part increment `i` instead of `k`? These changes will prevent `i` becoming greater than `leftsz` and `k` becoming greater than `rightsz`, so my earlier comment about replacing `if (i == leftsz)` with `if (i >= leftsz)` no longer applies.

Comment: @IanAbbott can you do an answer rather than remarks ? that allows to give the full corrected code, and also allow the OP to accept it to mark the question solved

Comment: @bruno: I've only been eyeballing the code so far. I'd like to run it before answering properly, but there is no [mcve].

Comment: @IanAbbott I just needed to add few lines to be able to run it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so looks like I was wrong as to why merge sort was failing.

As Ian Abbott said, `if (i == leftsz)` should be `if (i >= leftsz)` and the same should've went for `(k == rightsz)`. This prevents copying data past the end of the array. Thanks a lot!

Edit:

Additionally, I added in the following before the `j` loop:

```
for (int t = 0; t < sz; t++) {
    char *ptr = res + t*width;
    ptr = calloc(1, width);
    check_mem(ptr);
}
```

Without this section of code, the above doesn't work.

Comment: yes but this is not enough to work well, with `{ "asdfasfd", "werwar", "13234", "asdfasfd", "oioj" }` that produces `{ "asdfasfd", "asdfasfd", "werwar", "13234", "13234"}`

Comment: See my later comment on your question. I think it is incrementing the wrong variables.